# MacBook Pro 2014 makes constant hardware noise each few seconds

Tags: macbook-pro

The MacBook Pro Mid-2014 I have, recently started to make a strange noise every few seconds. It's like a sequence of short "clicks". I suspect it's some hardware trying to do something and not some noise coming out of the speakers. Listen to a sample here: https://voca.ro/185RA388D2Q2

The sound roughly comes from somewhere here (but that doesn't need to mean anything specific):

[image]

And ideas? I suspect that something will break down soon and I want to mitigate any bad things happening.

Comment: Try to control your fan using Mac Fan Control or Istat. See if setting the fan to zero removes the noise and setting the fan to high increases the intensity of the noise.

Comment: Also try to stop coreaudiod or unload kexts related to speaker to see if the problem is caused by the speaker: e.g. `sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext` and `sudo launchctl stop com.apple.audio.coreaudiod`.

Comment: when I try the first command I get `Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleHDA; services failed to terminate - 0xe00002c7. Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleHDA - (iokit/common) unsupported function`

Comment: Try to install windows using BootCamp to see if the noise also appears when you use Windows? If this issue does not appear when you run windows, run some stress test to confirm your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the left fan doesn't work anymore and the sound apparently is the fan trying (and failing) to start every ~5 seconds. I hope this can be replaced easily by some professional.

Thanks for your help, especially @Joy Jin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you’re exactly correct on where the sound is coming from, it’s the speaker.

The only moving parts in your Mac are the fans. They’re in the top left and right about an inch from the very edge of your mac. Where you’ve pointed out has nothing moving to make noise.

See this IFixit guide for internal reference on your marked location. If I’m indeed wrong, then you can find another possible reason by checking out the board in the guides.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+Speakers+Replacement/27691